# C structure for SPI 24-bit address device

Tags: c, microcontroller, spi

I am communicating with an SPI Audio record IC which has 24-bit address and 16-bit offset. I made a structure to read/write data from that device which has,

Command        - 1 byte
Address        - 3 byte (24-bit)
Offset address - 2 byte (16-bit)

During simulation (in proteous), it is found that 4th byte (MSB of address) is overlapped by 5th byte (LSB of Offset).

Following is the code. Please help what are the changes I need to do in the code.

```
typedef struct {
unsigned  char Command:8 ;
unsigned  long Addr:24;
unsigned  int Offset:16;
} ISD_Struct;
ISD_Struct ISD_Rec;
void main()
{
    address = 0x563412 ;
    OFFST   = 0x9A78 ;
    ISD_Rec.Command = 0xBC;
    ISD_Rec.Addr    = address;
    ISD_Rec.Offset  = OFFST;
    Write_SPI(&ISD_Rec,6); //sending  (1byte command + 3byte address + 2 byte offset)
    //Delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I made a union for char Command:8; and long Addr:24;  with a long variable. But I cannot control the MSB (4th byte).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a packed struct, the best method is

```
typedef struct {
unsigned  char Command;
unsigned  char Addr[3];
unsigned  char Offset[2];
} ISD_Struct;
ISD_Struct ISD_Rec;
```

If your compiler has no 24-bit data type (which is likely), then this is the only practical way.  This will also avoid alignment problems, and potential problems with endiann-ness.  Of course, you will have to do some byte shifting and masking to set the individual bytes, but that is straightforward.

You can add `assert(sizeof(ISD_REC == 6))` as a sanity check.

Comment: Thanks. As you noted "Of course, you will have to do some byte shifting and masking to set the individual bytes, but that is straightforward.", I was looking for methods to reduce those stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be defined as :

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long Command :8;
    unsigned long Addr :24;
    unsigned long Offset :16;
} ISD_Struct;
```

The type changing introduce padding to align `long` members. Note that most of the bit-fields mechanics are implementation defined, so check if this works as expected if you change your platform/compiler. You can probably use `offsetof` to make static checks.

Comment: But as 'xxyxyx' suggested, it may cause alignment problem, right?

Comment: @jkj There won't be any alignment problem. The whole structure will be aligned on 4 bytes because of the `long`, but the bit-field part is expected to not be aligned (how would you align 24 bits ?). The compiler will always use two or three operations to load/store the 24 bits part, because it has no other choice.

Comment: @jkj As I said, a lot of bit-field mechanics are compiler defined, but usually all the compilers have a similar implementation. This means there is a good chance that this code do what you want, and if it does, it is well defined and you can rely on it.